# Battleship board trouble on setting yo 5x5grid with python

Tags: python, append, range

I was learning how to set up a 5x5 battleship board, and couldn't quite understand how the lines below work.
First I've put a `[range(5)]` which produced `[0,1,2,3,4]` but why `append()`-ing "`board.append(['0']*5)`" makes all the numbers "0"?

```
board = []
for i in range(5):
  board.append(['0']*5)
print board

[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
```

Comment: What do you expect `['0']*5` to do?

Comment: `['0']*5` means 5 times '0'. It is exactly `['0', '0', '0', '0', '0']`. Try `board.append([i for i in range(5)])`

Comment: ow! I see, how could I miss tat. it make sense now.['0']*5=['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],and substituted the 0123and4! Thanks

Comment: Updated the question - formatting, clarification on the initial attempt